# How fill area in GoogleCharts AreaChart with gradient color?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

With my google Chart I use this options:

```
chartOptions: {
                hAxis: {
                    title: 'Tasks'
                },
                vAxis: {
                    title: 'Duration'
                },
                animation:{
                    duration: 2000,
                    startup: true
                },
                colors: ['#6f9654']


            }
```

How Can I change the color of the **area under the graph** and how can I fill it with a gradient? (I don't want to fill the background of the whole diagramm)

I don't find any docs on google documentation so far. Is it even possible? Is there a trick?

**UPDATE**: The Result on @whiteHats solution with my adaptations.:
[image]

Comment: Hey. It look super cool. I am struggled how to implement it. Could it be possible to see your solution with the adaptations?

Comment: See my comment under the correct answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

no options for gradient fill of the chart area,
but you can add your own...

first, add your gradient definition to the html somewhere.
this element should not be hidden with `display: none`,
otherwise, some browsers may ignore it.
setting the size to zero pixels seems to work.

```
<svg style="width:0;height:0;position:absolute;" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false">
  <linearGradient id="my-gradient" x2="1" y2="1">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#447799" />
    <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#224488" />
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#112266" />
  </linearGradient>
</svg>
```

next, we need to be able to identify the `<rect>` element that makes up the chart area.
here, a default background color is used.

```
var chartOptions = {
  chartArea: {
      backgroundColor: '#447799'
  },
  ...
```

then we find the `<rect>` element with the default background, and set the fill attribute.
normally, we could set the gradient fill on the chart's `'ready'` event,
but since you're using animation, the gradient will get overridden as the animation occurs.
we could also set the fill on the chart's `'animationfinish'` event,
but then there would not be a gradient during animation.

as such, we have to use a `MutationObserver`, and set the fill every time the svg is mutated (drawn).

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable({
    cols: [
      {label: 'x', type: 'number'},
      {label: 'y', type: 'number'}
    ],
    rows: [
      {c:[{v: 0}, {v: 25}]},
      {c:[{v: 5}, {v: 25}]},
      {c:[{v: 10}, {v: 25}]},
      {c:[{v: 15}, {v: 25}]},
      {c:[{v: 20}, {v: 25}]},
      {c:[{v: 25}, {v: 25}]},
      {c:[{v: 30}, {v: 25}]},
      {c:[{v: 40}, {v: 25}]},
      {c:[{v: 45}, {v: 25}]},
      {c:[{v: 50}, {v: 25}]},
      {c:[{v: 55}, {v: 25}]},
      {c:[{v: 60}, {v: 25}]},
      {c:[{v: 65}, {v: 25}]},
      {c:[{v: 70}, {v: 25}]}
    ]
  });

  var chartOptions = {
    chartArea: {
        backgroundColor: '#447799'
    },
    height: 600,
    hAxis: {
        title: 'Tasks'
    },
    vAxis: {
        title: 'Duration'
    },
    animation:{
        duration: 2000,
        startup: true
    },
    colors: ['#6f9654']
  };

  var container = document.getElementById("chart_div");
  var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(container);

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function () {
      container.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].setAttribute('xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg');
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(container.getElementsByTagName('rect'), function(rect) {
        if (rect.getAttribute('fill') === '#447799') {
          rect.setAttribute('fill', 'url(#my-gradient) #447799');
        }
      });
    });
    observer.observe(container, {
      childList: true,
      subtree: true
    });
  });

  chart.draw(dataTable, chartOptions);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<div id="chart_div"></div>

<svg style="width:0;height:0;position:absolute;" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false">
  <linearGradient id="my-gradient" x2="1" y2="1">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#447799" />
    <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#224488" />
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#112266" />
  </linearGradient>
</svg>
```

Comment: If I use "path" instead of "rect" it does the trick. and I changed my gradient to `<linearGradient id="my-gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%" >` which looks now very nice.

Comment: @helle Awesome! I implemented your version, and my chart is awesome now! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's documented in Google charts references page.
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart

Checkout the `annotations.boxStyle` section for gradients.

```
var options = {
  annotations: {
    boxStyle: {
      // Color of the box outline.
      stroke: '#888',
      // Thickness of the box outline.
      strokeWidth: 1,
      // x-radius of the corner curvature.
      rx: 10,
      // y-radius of the corner curvature.
      ry: 10,
      // Attributes for linear gradient fill.
      gradient: {
        // Start color for gradient.
        color1: '#fbf6a7',
        // Finish color for gradient.
        color2: '#33b679',
        // Where on the boundary to start and
        // end the color1/color2 gradient,
        // relative to the upper left corner
        // of the boundary.
        x1: '0%', y1: '0%',
        x2: '100%', y2: '100%',
        // If true, the boundary for x1,
        // y1, x2, and y2 is the box. If
        // false, it's the entire chart.
        useObjectBoundingBoxUnits: true
      }
    }
  }
};
```